# how to start using photobucket api for a beginner

Tags: api, photobucket

I want to know how to use photobucket api. I successfully created a login in photobucket.

I am following the guidelines given http://api-portal.anypoint.mulesoft.com/photobucket/api/photobucket-api/docs/getting-started

The first step i am failing is that http://developer.photobucket.com is redirecting to different page.

As it is written

```
Go to the Photobucket developer web site at developer.photobucket.com, agree to the terms of service, sign up, and get the API key.
```

I am not able to open developer.photobucket.com.

Answer (score 0):

I also see a redirect from developer.photobucket.com to photobucket.com. It seems that they incorrectly configured the redirect. The information about using Photobucket API required link was found in the [support section](http://support.photobucket.com/hc/en-us/articles/200724164-API-Requests-and-Information):

> Our engineers are working on a new API, with lots of changes, however,
>   this won't be available to users for a couple more months. Here is the
>   documentation on the [current API](http://pic.pbsrc.com/dev_help/WebHelpPublic/PhotobucketPublicHelp_Left.htm#CSHID=PB%20API%20Introduction.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/PB%20API%20Introduction.htm%7CSkinName=WebHelp).
>
> If you'd rather not wait for this updated API, and would like the
>   current iteration now, please send an email to our API request email
>   address with the following information:
>
> Your Photobucket username (This is the username for the account that
>   you have already created on Photobucket):  Your application name
>   (whatever you would like):  Do you require the key for commercial or
>   non-commercial purposes:
>
> All three of these answers are required!
>
> Send the API request to:  pbdl-api@photobucket.com
>
> The subject for the email should be: API Request